# Mysql fetch rows and count how many of them have a certain amount of characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of users that I'm querying. The users have 2 different types of userIDs one that is 15 characters long and the other that is 30 characters long. I want to run 1 query that tells me the total number of users, total users with a 15 character userID and total users with 30 character userID.

I would post some code but it wouldn't be helpful at all since the way I'm currently doing it involves looping though my results and then running another query to find the total users with 15 character ids. I believe this can be done using 1 query I'm just not sure how.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select count(*) as totalusers,
       sum(length(userID) = 15) as Num15s,
       sum(length(userID) = 30) as Num30s,
       sum(length(userID) not in (15, 30)) as OopsIWasWrongSomeAreNotLength15Or30
from users;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I like the name of the non 15 and 30 user ids :D

Comment: +1. Yep. This is the right approach. In the general case, there's one more tiny crack... `OopsSomeAreNull`

Comment: Just for my own knowledge what if I wanted to sort by userID that has 30 characters and say no hyphens in the user id? Could this query be edited to accommodate that or would it need a subquery?

Comment: @Dave . . . This query returns one row with counts because that is what the question asks for.  It doesn't make sense to "sort" a result set that has only one row.  If you have a different question in mind, you should ask the question, including sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry I worded the question poorly I'm still looking for a count. I'm just looking for a count that is 30 characters long and doesn't contain hyphens.

Comment: @Dave . . . You can add another column:  `sum(length(userID) = 30 and userID not like '%-%')`.